# Access violation with glGenBuffers() with GLEW initialization in the correct order

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I've read that when setting up GLEW, you have to initialize it after the window context has been created. I have done so below, but the issue is that I still get access violations with calls such as glGenBuffers() is made. The error check also isn't set off. Is it due to the placement of the GLEW initialization/how I create the RenderWindow? Putting the code into the main() function without the class works just fine.

```
Engine() : sf::RenderWindow(){
        // setup the SFML renderwindow
        string windowTitle = "OpenGL";

        sf::ContextSettings contextSettings;
        contextSettings.antialiasingLevel = 4;
        contextSettings.depthBits = 64;

        sf::RenderWindow::create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), windowTitle, sf::Style::Resize | sf::Style::Close, contextSettings);

        // setup GLEW
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        GLenum err = glewInit();
        if(err != GLEW_OK){
            printf("ERROR: GLEW failed to initialize.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        glViewport(0, 0, sf::RenderWindow::getSize().x, sf::RenderWindow::getSize().y);
        ...
}
```

Comment: Please show as main function where everything was fine

Answer (score 0):

I think try without using `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`. This is specifically used when you are creating OpenGL context in Core profile and want to use it with glew. As with your case you are leaving the type of context created on library by default. This by default context mostly will be created by your library`s create window function and mostly that will be compatible context. If that doesn't work then see how to create context with library you are using, create context in core profile and put `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`.

Like glut has function to create context with specific version and Core profile you must be having functions to do that. Create context specifically in Core profile with say 4.1 version and use

```
 glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
   GLenum err = glewInit();
   if(err != GLEW_OK){
   printf("ERROR: GLEW failed to initialize.\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

else just remove call to `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` and see

Comment: I think my error is how I create the RenderWindow. I just set it up so the window is created in main() and passes it through the render function to display it and it works fine there.

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that create method only create window class, but not create/display window. That could be the problem. Make sure that window is displayed before glewInit called